# Link to entity in console

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to link to the page for an entity in the Google Cloud console.  Here is what a link looks like:

> console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/edit?key=0%2F%7C8%2F{{kind}}%7C19%2Fid:{{id}}&project={{project}}&ns=&kind={{kind}}

A shorter version of the link works and I decoded the % characters for clarity:

> console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/edit?key=0/|**8**/{{kind}}|**19**/id:{{id}}

I put the numbers 8 and 19 in bold because they are different for different entities, and because I don't know those numbers, I can't create the link.

Anyone know how to create such a link?  With the old console, you could do it with a urlsafe key...

Comment: I am interested in this question, but at the same time curious, why would you need such a url?

Comment: I have my own admin console for my app to keep track of what is going on, and I like to have links to the entities there because it saves me the trouble of doing a query.

Comment: @minocha, I don't understand your question...  My code is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it myself and the URL-safe key still works, so if this worked for you earlier why not just use that one?

https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/edit?key=...

Comment: Since the new console now uses key in another way I didn't think to try that, but it works.  Thank you.